# Rails 3 scaffold and i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, scaffold

When scaffolding in Rails 3 the generator does this:

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
```

But what about i18n? The messages get translated but why the hardcoded headline? Am I supposed to translate that manually? That doesn't seem very DRY?

Regards,

Jacob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can override scaffold default behavior by downloading the files [here on github](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/templates) and place em in your `lib/templates/erb/scaffold`. When you generate scaffold it realize the templates are there and use those.

`<% this code is executed and probably result in html %>`, `<%% this is converted to snippet %>`, it was not that difficult and then you can perform all your personalizations, but to have the `yml` file automatically generated could be harder, anyway you can still get your templates almost done automatically.

To answer your question I do too think scaffold could be improved, but I read everywhere developers prefer to write their own code from scratch. Therefor I think, efforts are focused on improving other features. Scaffold remains at the very least a useful generator to understand and get familiar with the logic when you're a beginner.

Comment: Note -- it's `lib/templates/erb/scaffold` with a plural `templates`

Comment: scaffold is also useful to develop admin functionality

Comment: That's interesting -- I hadn't considered that. You just add the hooks to the templates that allow/prevent certain actions based on admin rights?

Comment: I mean that usually admin has control over the whole model and don't need an advanced interface, one line in the console, one css file, before_filter require_admin and job done.

Answer (score 0):

I think that scaffolding is more a hint than a final template.

you may want to add translation simply substituing `"prohibited this user from being saved:"` with `t('my_message')` and dding `'my_message: whatever'` to the `en.yml`. Adding a translation you have no repetitions and the dry principle is safe.

Just a comment aside: I seldomly use a message like *"4 errors prohibited this user from being saved"*. In my experience is more common just to list all the errors occurred and to display the wrong field in a kind of red.